# Sort array of numbers with total number of digits

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given a array of natural, each number can be a different number of digits, but guaranteed that the total number of digits of all the numbers together is `m`.

For example, if a three numbers:

```
2,3,1081 then m = 6.
```

I need algorithm that sorts the numbers in the array in `O(m)`.

I tried with radix sort but its no good for me.

Comment: `but its no good for me` why? describing what's wrong will help us understand your problem.

Comment: because for radix i need to know the digits length of the numbers

Comment: I wonder how is it possible in `O(m)`. Imagine situation, `m=1.000.000` and each number consists of only one digit. Obviously, to sort that you'll have to apply some regular sorting algorithm which can not be `O(m)` (since in this case `m` is equal to array elements count) - only `O(m log(m))`. I guess this is worst case, but still - that's why I'm doubt. Or you'll need to use some extra-space (but that depends of what complexity is important)

Comment: @AlmaDo There are algorithms for sorting objects with special properties, such as numbers with limited number of digits, faster than `O(N*log N)`. For example, RadixSort is linear in the number of elements.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight again. depends. To be correct, radix sort is bound to alphabet's length (and so it even is involved into complexity measurement). But in this case alphabet is too narrow, I think (only 0-9) - in terms of meaningful values. I may be wrong (because didn't try that) - but still that's why I was doubt

Answer (score 5):

Radix sort can definetly solve this problem in `O(m)`. Do a radix sort starting from least significant bit, and move torwards the most significant bit iteratively.

Whenever you encounter a 'non existing digit' (for example, 2nd iteration for the number '5'), treat it as -1 - so it will be the first in the array generated by this iteration.

After each 'round' reduce the array size and 'trim' all the numbers that you have just passed (that you just treated as '-1' for this iteration).

This requires examining each digit in each element exactly one time, and in addition - for each element, one time when you treat it as -1.

This gives you `O(m+n)` complexity, and since `n<m` - this is `O(m)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The 3rd 'paragraph' in the answer addresses this issue. After you treat a number one time as '-1', you can trim the array - the prefix of it that start with -1 is already sorted. In your example, you will first do an iteration for all 501 numbers, then you will do a 2nd iteration, treating 500 numbers as '-1', and after the 2nd iteration - you can trim the array, and continue searching in the subarray `a[500:501]`. No more accesses at all for the `a[0:500]` elements - this subarray is sorted and every element is where it should be.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight (cont) - so, you need to examine 1000 digits, and for each number one time treat it as -1, which gives you 1000+501 <= 2*1000

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Not sure what you mean, this is a radix sort variant, and I am sorting each time according to one digit. Each number with 'k' digits will be handled exactly 'k+1' time, each time using different digit in it.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think the comments clarified this algorithm is correct and runs in the desired complexity. :|

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense (I have no idea why they downvoted this...)

Comment: @amit why didn't you use classic radix sort? is there a problem with using classic radix sort that will increase the run time for this problem?

Comment: @DarkLeader Classic radix sort will mean to inspect each integer more times than its number of digits (It will be inspected all the way like the longest digit integer in the input). In this case you exceed O(m).

Answer (score 0):

Implement a bucket sort, by placing each number into a bucket by the number of digits it contains. By doing this, you know that all the numbers in a bucket of *n+1* digits will be greater than all the numbers in the bucket containing *n* digits. Because of this, you will only have to sort the numbers in each bucket, then combining them into the original list again making the sort linear.

Comment: Default implementation for Bucket sort uses Insertion Sort to sort the linked lists inside the buckets, but in order to achieve O(m) we should use Radix Sort to sort the linked lists inside the buckets